# Collecting the Distance between locations by city and state name

Tags: python, web-scraping, distance, geography

I am writing a set of python files that overall, collects the distances between two locations by `citystatename` and writes it as a dataframe as follows.

```
cleveland,ohio --> south bend,indiana --> 125mi   
columbus,ohio --> dallas,texas--> 471mi
# ... and so on.
```

there could be tens of thousands of distances that need to be looked up, and written.
my issue now is that i cannot find a reliable source where i can look up the distances between two locations.

I have tried using the 40gb citystate matrix from The National Bureau of Economic research. After spending many hours learning to work with this file via Dask, i finally realized that a large amount of the distances that i need to look up were not in the file.

i tried to slowly and reasonably scrape various websites that give that information, but then the site permanently bans my ip.

what i need very specificially, is the exact information that i presented earlier.
i expect the source to take `origin_citystatename, destination_cityname`as input.
and the output i need, is simply the distance in miles between those two locations.

what website, or api can i use that provides that information in a reasonable amount of time? such as 1 request per second for 5k requests, for example. sidenote, there are a limited number of locations i need to look up. so once i collect mostly all of the distances, i might need to only find 5 or 10 more distances per day.

Comment: Are you. looking for road distance or straight line distance?  For the latter, you just need the lat/lon for each city and some math.

Comment: Road distance, and could i ask you to elaborate? That would help me immensely.

Comment: If you're just looking for the "as the crow flies" distance between two points, this is relatively straightforward.  Just Google Latitude/Longitude distance.  There are the simpler formulas (the Earth is a sphere) or the slightly more complicated formulas (the Earth is slightly oval.)

Comment: You can try `https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/` then build a graph using networkx or any other library, and do a shortest path algorithm between each place if you need the distance if you are traveling by road. For the geodesic distance, try PROJ

Comment: @FrankYellin the lat/lng idea might work, but the trouble now is that i would still need to acquire the latitude and longitude of potentially tens of thousands of locations. or many more. which still puts me in a bind. is there maybe a way to calculate or figure that out as well?

Comment: @FrankYellin i was able to use the python packages haversine and geopy together to convert citystatenames into latlong, and then easily get the distances between two locations.

Comment: Well, getting tens of thousands of long/lats is a lot less than getting distances between millions of pairs of cities.